Extracting int values from a string (in different formats) using a regex
I have a string value (football score) in my Pandas dataset. I would like to extract the home goals and the away goals from this score.
The score can be written in a couple of ways (sometimes it is won on penalties and presented with brackets.
Standard score:
"4-2" I would like to extract 4 as the home goals and 2 as the away goals.
Won on penalties:
"(5) 2-3 (4)" I would like to extract 2 as the home goals and 3 as the away goals and ignore the brackets
Is there a reg-ex (or 2) that would give me the 2 values I require in both instances. Maybe checking for the "-" and take the number either side of it?

You could write import re; match = re.search('(?<!\()(?P<home>\d+) *- *(?P<away>\d+)', '(5) 2-3 (4)'); match.group('home') #=> 2; match.group('away') #=> 3. (?<!\() is a negative lookbehind that asserts that the match in not preceded by '('. Demo

If you need goals in separate columns with numeric dtype:
df = pd.DataFrame({"Score": ["4-2", "(5) 2-3 (4)", "1-1"]})

df[["Home Goals", "Away Goals"]] = df["Score"].str.extract(r"(\d+)-(\d+)")
df[["Home Goals", "Away Goals"]] = df[["Home Goals", "Away Goals"]].astype(int)

         Score  Home Goals  Away Goals
0          4-2           4           2
1  (5) 2-3 (4)           2           3
2          1-1           1           1


A possible solution is the following, where df = pd.DataFrame({'col': ["(5) 2-3 (4)"]}):
df['col'].str.extract(r'(\d+-\d+)')

Output:
     0
0  2-3

